# how to check linux X11 version?

Tags: linux, version, x11

I need to read X11 source code, since there are a number of X11 versions, like:
X11R1
X11R2
...
X11R7.7

how can I find out which version of X11 my ubuntu 10.04 has installed?

thank you.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Filter the output of the [`xdpyinfo`](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.7/doc/man/man1/xdpyinfo.1.xhtml) command

```
xdpyinfo | grep version
```

will output something like

```
version number:    11.0
X.Org version: 1.20.4
```

Comment: If you only want the second line you can do `xdpyinfo | grep version:` and if you only want the version number you can do `xdpyinfo | grep version: | cut -d' ' -f3`

Comment: It's shocking that this is the accepted answer. How does a version like 1.20.4 relate to the question about X11RX.X? Is this X11R1.20.4?

Answer (score -3):

To not confuse you too much, just type in the following:

```
root@your-computer:/# x11 -version
```

This should provide you the information you were looking for.

Comment: Same here on Gentoo Linux